# how to create dropdown menu in django

Tags: python, html, django

I'm new to django and would like to create a drop down menu for options. I'm confused as to what I should include in my forms.py and how to call that form on my index.html.

My forms.py

```
    from django import forms

    class MyModel2(forms.Form):
       class Meta:
           model = MyModel
           fields = ['color']
```

My index.html

```
    <form method="POST" action = "">{% csrf_token %}

            <p>Choose color</p> {{ form.color}}
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit!"/>

        </form>
```

My models.py

```
    from __future__ import unicode_literals

    from django.db import models

    COLOR_CHOICES = (
       ('green','GREEN'),
       ('blue', 'BLUE'),
       ('red','RED'),
       ('orange','ORANGE'),
       ('black','BLACK'),
    )

    class MyModel(models.Model):
        color = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=COLOR_CHOICES, default='green')
```

Thank you!

Comment: and please include your views?

Answer (score 2):

So your only problem is that you declared your model field as a `CharField` while trying to use a `forms.Form` for your form instead of a `forms.ModelForm`. If you're going to use `forms.Form` you'll need to declare a [ChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield) to get a select dropdown automatically.

You could also make use of `forms.ModelForm` instead of `forms.Form` in your form and I'm pretty sure that would make it work as well. ModelForm and Forms don't handle fields the same way unfortunately.

Comment: ChoiceField is a form field, not a model field.

Comment: @guillermochamorro He's using a `forms.Form` not a `forms.ModelForm` so yes, he would need to use a `ChoiceField` in his form. I've royally confused myself when typing so editing to make things better xD

Answer (score 1):

Widgets are probably the answer here, but you don't necessarily need to use a ModelForm (unless, as it seems like, you are wanting to use models with you form, but you don't have to.) Try something like this:

```
# forms.py
class MyModel2(forms.Form):
   color = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select)
```

and...

```
<!-- index.html -->
<form method="POST" action = "ACTION_OR_VIEW_URL_ON_SUBMIT_HERE">{% csrf_token %}
    <label for="colorSelect">Choose color</label>
    <select type="text" id="colorSelect" name="colorSelect">
        <option selected>GREEN</option>
        <option>BLUE</option>
        <option>RED</option>
        <option>ORANGE</option>
        <option>BLACK</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit!"/>
</form>
```

Or, if you do want to use a ModelForm, check out guillermo chamorro's answer to see how to use widgets with them.

Answer (score -1):

First use `ModelForm` instead of `Form`, then you can use `widgets` attributes:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

# Mind the name of your form!!

class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = MyModel
       fields = ['color']
       widgets = {
           # Here you define what input type should the field have
           'color': Select(attrs = { 
               'class': 'form-control',
           }),
       }
```

You don't "call that form on my index.html". Yo use `views` to call the form and set the html template to use.

Using class based views you got:

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .models import MyModel
from .forms import MyModelForm

class ColourCreateView(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    template_name = 'index.html'
    form_class = MyModelForm
```

Comment: what 'class' : 'form-control' does

Comment: @VarunSharma this is an old answer and I haven't been using django for a long time, but to answer your question it's the html attributes of the widget, so something like `<select class="form-control"...`, but I can't say if this kind of code is still possible in modern versions of django.